# How can i include multiple Plotly graphs in a webpage?

Tags: django

i am trying to build an application that shows plots generated out of data in the db . I want to publish these in a grid in same webpage now can i do this

**Here is my views.py**

```
 
    unique_m = df['metric'].unique()
    hlist = []
    for m in unique_m:
        df2 = df.loc[df['metric'] == m]
        fig = px.line(df2, x="date", y="value", title=m, width=700, height=500)
        file = fig.write_html("Templates/plots/%s.html" % m )
        hlist.append(file)

    context1 = {'plotly_div': hlist}

    return render(request, 'index.html', context1 )
```

**Here is my index.html**

```
   {% extends "base.html" %}
     {% block content %}
      <div>
      <!--  {% autoescape off %} -->
         <div style="margin: 0 auto; width:855px; height:500px;">
           {% for x in plotly_div %}
              <div style="margin: 0 auto; width:855px height:500px;">
               <iframe src="{{ plotly_div }}" style="border:none;"        style="height:500px;width:800px;" seamless="seamless" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
         </div> 
         {% endfor %}

     </div>

    </div>`

      <!--  {% endautoescape %}}  -->
      {% endblock content %}
```